# Do ad blockers read include statements?

Tags: include, adblock

First of all apologies if this was answered elsewhere but I couldn't find anything when I searched.

My question is rather simple, do ad blockers read include statements and as a result block the calling of files that have the word banner in it, say banner-468.html?

Answer (score 0):

apologies for answering my question but there have been no replies so I wanted to check if the question was stupid or if it somehow slipped through the cracks...